# Selecting top 5 grouped by, and ordered by average of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've searched for ways to do this but am not sure how to apply suggestions in my particular scenario, and I also don't know which approach would be the best or most accurate taking into account context of the data.

I am looking for the best way to select top performers from a table that contains scores for employees, given for the same measurements multiple times for a particular test.  So an employee may be evaluated many times using the same test/measurements over time, and I am trying to select the top performers for a given period.  In this example, the measurements are recorded in columns Question1 and Question2, and the employee is designated in the column EmployeeID.  The scales of the scores are different by column, and by test, but all with a min of 0 or 1.  In the sample data, test 1000 has columns Question1 (0-10) and Question2 (1-7), but you don't know the scales for sure based on the data, you only know that each column has a min of 0 or 1 and can be null meaning that value should be excluded from averaging calculations.  I want to be able to say, give me the two top performers for test 1000 and order them accordingly based on that performance.

```
   ID            TestID        Question1       Question2       Question3       EmployeeID
   1              1000             10             null            null             12
   2              1000             10              7              null             12
   3              1000             10              7              null             12
   4              1000             10              7              null             12
   5              1000             10              7              null             12
   6              1000             10              7              null             5
   7              1000             10              7              null             5
   8              1000             10              7              null             5
   9              1000             10              7              null             5
   10             1000             10              7              null             5
   11             1000             10              7              null             5
   12             1000             10              7              null             5
   13             1000             10              7              null             5
   14             1000             10             null            null             5
   15             1000             10              7              null             5
   16             2000             5               10              10              3
   17             2000             5               0               3               3
   18             2000            null             9               8               6
   19             2000             5               10              9               6
   20             2000            null             10              9               7
   21             2000            null             10              9               7
```

In this example, for test 1000, if I get the top two performers, ranked, the result should be employee 5 and employee 12 ranked the same, because though they both have 10s and 7s and each include one null, which shouldn't be considered.

This SQL was suggested to me but it doesn't seem to work the way I want.  The resulting SumAve ends up at 8.5789 for employee 5 and 8.6667 for employee 12, which doesn't seem right because they have the same averages of their scores that were recorded, and they shouldn't be penalized for having any nulls.  But even if they were, that is the opposite of what I thought would be the case since employee 5 has more records (7s) I would think their average would be impacted less by a missing/low score.

```
SELECT TOP 2
  EmployeeID
 ,NoOfResults
 ,Question1
 ,Question2
 ,Question3
 ,SumAve
FROM (SELECT
    [EmployeeID]
   ,COUNT(*) AS NoOfResults
   ,AVG([Question1]) AS Question1
   ,AVG([Question2]) AS Question2
   ,AVG([Question3]) AS Question3
   ,SUM(ISNULL([Question1], 0) + ISNULL([Question2], 0) + ISNULL([Question3], 0)) / 
    SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN Question1 IS NULL THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END +
    CASE
      WHEN Question2 IS NULL THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END +
    CASE
      WHEN Question3 IS NULL THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END) AS SumAve
  FROM Table1
  WHERE TestID = '1000'
  GROUP BY [EmployeeID] perform
ORDER BY SumAve DESC, EmployeeID ASC
```

Also, one last wrench to throw in, it's possible for a record to contain all null values for Question1, Question2 and Question3.  Meaning the test was given but no scores were recorded (for whatever reason).  In this case, again, the null values should be ignored leaving an employee with no rank or lowest rank / not included if that's their only record but using other records if they exist. 
 And I suppose it's possible for one employee to have multiple records but nulls in one column on all records, so I've added that as well.  Let me know if that's the straw that broke the camel's back though because if that's the case I might be able to change something in the available data.

Thanks for looking at this, your help is much appreciated.

---

Update -

Using @scsimon's suggested method doesn't seem to give me what I'm looking for.  It appears that the result is affected by nulls, which earlier I mentioned shouldn't be used to penalize the employee's overall score/ranking.  In the following example, employees 10 and 5 both have highest scores (10s and 7s), but employee 5 has one score missing which should not affect their ranking.  Employee 12 has scores that aren't perfect (one score of 9 instead of 10), which should reflect a lower ranking than employees 10 and 5, but as you can see employee 5 ends up lower, so they are being penalized for a missing score, which they should not.  The ranking for test 1000 should have employees 10, 5, 11 and 13 at the top, with employee 12 below them.

*SQL for data*

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
 ,TestID INT
 ,Question1 INT
 ,Question2 INT
 ,Question3 INT
 ,EmployeeID INT
)
INSERT INTO @table
  VALUES 
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, NULL, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 9, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1001, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1001, NULL, 6, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, NULL, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 13),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 13)
```

*Data*

```
     ID       TestID   Question1  Question2  Question3  EmployeeID
     18        1000        10         7         null        5     
     19        1000        10         7         null        5     
     20        1000        10         7         null        5     
     21        1000        10         7         null        5     
     22        1000        10         7         null        5     
     23        1000        10         7         null        5     
     24        1000        10         7         null        5     
     25        1000        10         7         null        5     
     26        1000        10        null       null        5     
     27        1000        10         7         null        5     
     1         1000        10         7         null        10    
     2         1000        10         7         null        10    
     3         1000        10         7         null        10    
     4         1000        10         7         null        10    
     5         1000        10         7         null        10    
     6         1000        10        null       null        11    
     7         1000        10         7         null        11    
     8         1000        10         7         null        11    
     9         1000        10         7         null        11    
     10        1000        10         7         null        11    
     11        1000        10         7         null        12    
     12        1000        9          7         null        12    
     13        1000        10         7         null        12    
     14        1000        10         7         null        12    
     15        1000        10         7         null        12    
     16        1001        10         7         null        12    
     17        1001       null        6         null        12    
     28        1000        10         7         null        13    
     29        1000        10         7         null        13
```

*Suggestion 1: SQL for result*

```
SELECT
  t.EmployeeID
 ,t.TestID
 ,SUM(ISNULL(Question1, 0) + ISNULL(Question2, 0) + ISNULL(Question3, 0)) / (COUNT(t.TestID) * 1.00) AS Ranking
FROM @table t
GROUP BY t.EmployeeID
        ,t.TestID
ORDER BY t.TestID,
Ranking DESC
```

*Suggestion 1: Result*

```
   EmployeeID        TestID          Ranking    
       10             1000            17.0      
       13             1000            17.0      
       12             1000            16.8      
        5             1000            16.3      
       11             1000            15.6      
       12             1001            11.5
```

And with regard to the other suggestion, it doesn't appear to be outputting what I need either -

*Suggestion 2: SQL for result*

```
SELECT
  EmployeeID
 ,TestID
 ,SUM(ISNULL(Q1, 0) + ISNULL(Q2, 0) + ISNULL(Q3, 0)) / MIN(CASE
    WHEN Q1 IS NULL THEN 0.0
    ELSE 1.0
  END +
  CASE
    WHEN Q2 IS NULL THEN 0.0
    ELSE 1.0
  END +
  CASE
    WHEN Q3 IS NULL THEN 0.0
    ELSE 1.0
  END) AS AverageScore
FROM cte
GROUP BY EmployeeID
        ,TestID
ORDER BY TestID
, AverageScore
```

*Suggestion 2: Result*

```
   EmployeeID        TestID       AverageScore  
        5             1000             8.5      
       10             1000             8.5      
       11             1000             8.5      
       12             1000             8.5      
       13             1000             8.5      
       12             1001             8.5
```

Comment: so do you want to take the highest score per question per employee, or the highest average of the test per employee? What i'm asking is, should the employee's average be based off their highest score for each question (even if they came from different test attempts), or based off the single test which theri avg of the question scores was the highest?

Comment: Single test I believe.  For test 1000, rank the employees on how well they did over all of the times they took that test.  It doesn't matter to me what their highest score is, because it can go up and down as time goes on based on outside influences.  The thing that matters is their performance over time.  You can think of it as firefighters physical performance testing. They may have a good day or bad day but over time they need to meet some threshold and hopefully improve performance, and in the meantime you want to track ranking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.  Hopefully someone else can benefit from it.  Turns out it was a simple adjustment.  Basically I am getting the averages of employees scores for each question, and also adding them together to create an index so that I can rank them.  I've tried multiple real data scenarios and it seems to be an accurate method of measuring and ranking for each scenario.  Here is some sample data that demonstrates a few scenarios.  Also, in my example I am combining rank across both tests (in this case they would be the same tests fundamentally but different revisions).

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (
  ID INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
 ,TestID INT
 ,Question1 FLOAT
 ,Question2 FLOAT
 ,Question3 FLOAT
 ,EmployeeID INT
)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (
  EmployeeID INT
 ,Description VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @table1
  VALUES (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 10),
  (1000, 10, NULL, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 11),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 9, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1001, 10, 7, NULL, 12),
  (1001, NULL, 6, NULL, 12),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, NULL, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 5),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 13),
  (1000, 10, 7, NULL, 13),
  (1000, NULL, NULL, NULL, 14)
INSERT INTO @table2
  VALUES (10, 'peter (10s & 7s)')
  ,(11, 'michael (10s & 7s, x7)')
  ,(12, 'samir (mixed)')
  ,(13, 'milton (10s & 7s, <count)')
  ,(5, 'tom (10s & 7s, x7)')
  ,(14, 'bob (nulls)')

SELECT
  t1.TestID
 ,t1.EmployeeID
 ,t1.Question1
 ,t1.Question2
 ,t1.Question3
FROM @table1 t1
INNER JOIN @table2 t2
  ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
ORDER BY t1.EmployeeID, TestID

SELECT
  t1.EmployeeID
 ,t2.Description
 ,AVG(t1.Question1) AS Question1
 ,AVG(t1.Question2) AS Question2
 ,AVG(t1.Question3) AS Question3
 ,COUNT(t1.EmployeeID) AS NoOfTests
 ,ISNULL(AVG(t1.Question1), 0) + ISNULL(AVG(t1.Question2), 0) + ISNULL(AVG(t1.Question3), 0) AS Rank
FROM @table1 t1
INNER JOIN @table2 t2
  ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
WHERE t1.TestID = 1000
OR t1.TestID = 1001
GROUP BY t1.EmployeeID
        ,t2.Description
ORDER BY rank DESC, NoOfTests DESC
```

Test data:

```
TestID   EmployeeID Question1  Question2  Question3 
 1000        5         10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        5         10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        5         10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        5         10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        5         10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        5         10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        5         10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        5         10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        5         10.0       null       null   
 1000        5         10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        10        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        10        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        10        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        10        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        10        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        11        10.0       null       null   
 1000        11        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        11        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        11        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        11        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        12        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        12        9.0        7.0        null   
 1000        12        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        12        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        12        10.0       7.0        null   
 1001        12        10.0       7.0        null   
 1001        12        null       6.0        null   
 1000        13        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        13        10.0       7.0        null   
 1000        14        null       null       null
```

Result data:

```
EmployeeID         Description        Question1  Question2  Question3  NoOfTests  Rank           
     5         tom (10s & 7s, x7)       10.0        7.0       null        10      17.0           
    10          peter (10s & 7s)        10.0        7.0       null         5      17.0           
    11       michael (10s & 7s, x7)     10.0        7.0       null         5      17.0           
    13      milton (10s & 7s, <count)   10.0        7.0       null         2      17.0           
    12            samir (mixed)         9.833      6.857      null         7      16.69          
    14             bob (nulls)          null        null      null         1       0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the Employee shouldn't be docked for not answering a question, I think this should do it.

```
declare @table table(ID int, TestID int, Question1 int, Question2 int, Question3 int, EmployeeID int)
insert into @table
values
(1,1000,10,null,null,12),
(2,1000,10,7,null,12),
(3,1000,10,7,null,12),
(4,1000,10,7,null,12),
(5,1000,10,7,null,12),
(6,1000,10,7,null,5),
(7,1000,10,7,null,5),
(8,1000,10,7,null,5),
(9,1000,10,7,null,5),
(10,1000,10,7,null,5),
(11,1000,10,7,null,5),
(12,1000,10,7,null,5),
(13,1000,10,7,null,5),
(14,1000,10,null,null,5),
(15,1000,10,7,null,5),
(16,2000,5,10,10,3),
(17,2000,5,0,3,3),
(18,2000,null,9,8,6),
(19,2000,5,10,9,6),
(20,2000,null,10,9,7),
(21,2000,null,10,9,7)

;with cte as(
    select 
        TestID, 
        EmployeeID,
        max(Question1) as Q1,
        max(Question2) as Q2,
        max(Question3) as Q3
    from 
        @table
    group by
        TestID, 
        EmployeeID)

select 
    EmployeeID,
    TestID,
    Sum(isnull(Q1,0) + isnull(Q2,0) + isnull(Q3,0)) / min(case when Q1 is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end + case when Q2 is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end + case when Q3 is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end ) as AverageScore
from 
    cte
group by
    EmployeeID,
    TestID
order by
    TestID
    ,AverageScore
```

Or, if i was incorrect in the assumption above, this query is more like what you want which is average per employeeid based on their individual attempts.

```
select 
    t.EmployeeID,
    t.TestID,
    Sum(isnull(Question1,0) + isnull(Question2,0) + isnull(Question3,0)) / (count(t.TestID) * 1.00)
from 
    @table t
group by
    t.EmployeeID,
    t.TestID
order by
    t.TestID
```

Comment: I'm playing around with it some more to see if I have any questions, but it looks like it does what I want. Thank you.

Comment: I added another question regarding your suggestion.

Comment: I don't understand your edit, but if you have a new question it's best to accept an answer and open a new question regarding that. I think what you are going to want to research is `WITH TIES`

Comment: Please see my latest edit.  Let me know if I'm using the wrong approach or misunderstanding something.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious, would the correct approach involve average each question for an employee then averaging those averages?